# MySQL/SQL - Corelative table rows - is that possible?

Tags: mysql

I'd like to create some kind of game. I have got two tables in my database:

- `users`
- `agents`

In `agents` i store data specific for virtual characters, for example number of points they grant when chosen.

In `users` there's user specific data - for this case only these matter: `agent1`, `agent2`, `agent3`, `points`

User can pick three different agents (`agent1`, `agent2`, `agent3` will be set as corresponding `id` from `agents`. The `points` row however should be exactly what's the sum of points of every `agents` corresponding character.

How may I achieve some kind of corelation in MySQL database so that `points` would update based on chosen `agents`?

Comment: Make points a view, not a table, or use a trigger?

Comment: Welp, in my opinion that is a terrible table design, but if you already insist on shooting yourself in the foot: you could always update both users and agents table every time you change one of the agents points (then run a second query to update the sum). Or you can drop that idea of points column and sum it up in a query when you retrieve data.

Comment: @AntonioTehSumtin I'm learning from mistakes mostly so would be utmostly glad to hear from you what is a better way to design it! :) Actually dropping points column seems really reasonable if i can't really make a dynamic relative table.

Comment: Just to be clear; 1 agent can only belong to 1 user, and 1 user can have many agents?

Comment: @AntonioTehSumtin 1 user can have up to 3 agents, and agents can belong to unlimited users at a time actually

Comment: In that case you have a many to many relationship between these tables. you need to create a pivot table connecting them and query your data accordingly, please study into the topic of table relationships. I know you want fast answers but this is a learning process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would normally have a third table, so:

```
users (user_id,points)

user_agent(user_id,agent_id)
```

Answer (score 1):

Can't be done with a relation, but could be done with a Trigger. If I were doing it, I'd just use a sql query in the game code any time a choice is made.

Comment: So I should just SELECT agents points value once he is chosen and UPDATE users points afterwards right? no shortcuts for this? :P

Comment: Triggers are to be avoided at all costs, especially for begginers, there is always a better way to process things rather than using triggers.